# Which definition of confidence interval is correct, or are they the same thing?

Tags: confidence-interval, standard-deviation, standard-error

Wondering 1) which of the two ways of calculating confidence intervals is correct, and 2) if they both are correct, are they the same or different? How do they reconcile?

1. CI = [Coef x1 ± 2*SE(coef x1)]
2. CI = [Sample mean ± Margin of error]

Number 1's source is page 76 in ISLR 2nd Edition:

[image]

Number 2's source is page 7 here: https://www.westga.edu/academics/research/vrc/assets/docs/confidence_intervals_notes.pdf

[image]

Comment: The first formula is a little sloppy and is *only* kinda correct for $\text{Confidence level }(CL) = 0.95$. The precise expression—assuming *normality* of the distribution of $\beta$—is $CI = \widehat{\beta}\pm z_{1 - \frac{CL}{2}}s_{\beta}$; if $CL=0.95$, then $z_{1 - \frac{CL}{2}} = 1.96$ which is only approximately 2.

Comment: I see, then that means 1.96*SE lines up with Margin of Error, great! However, does this mean that B1 (the coefficient), is the same as the sample mean described in the 2nd formula?

Comment: Yes in a sense: an OLS regression coefficient $\widehat{\beta}$ is estimated by something like the mean change in $y$ given the mean change in $x$, with the error term of $y|x$ assumed distributed normal..

Comment: Aside: very often the error terms or sample means are assumed to be *T* distributed, rather than normally distributed (which is why we often see *t* test statistics for coefficients). In such a case, the $z_{(1-CL)/2}$ term (sorry for the error in my first comment) would instead be given by $t_{(1-CL)/2}$ for a given degrees of freedom. When $\alpha=0.05$, the $t_{(1-CL)/2}$ term can be greater than or less than 2 (or even, improbably, equal to it).

Answer (score 4):

Neither definition is the most general definition of a confidence interval, and you don’t have to get that exotic to find situations where both are inappropriate. In particular, both give intervals that are symmetric about the point estimate, and a confidence interval for variance, for example, does not have this property when it is calculated the parametric way that inverts a chi-squared test.

Comment: Thanks, do you mind elaborating on the correct way of calculating the confidence interval then? In an easy to understand way please, sorry am not a PhD in statistics.

Comment: @Katsu There are many ways to calculate confidence intervals, depending on what you want to estimate and what assumptions you are willing to make.

Comment: @Dave I think your first sentence is misleading. The two CIs given in the question are not wrong; they *are* both reasonable CIs for certain cases (for certain parameters, under certain assumptions, and with 2 as an approx to 1.96...). I suggest rewording your first sentence to "Neither of them is the most general definition of a confidence interval."